# How to fix shower handle that keeps falling off and won't stay screwed

Tags: shower

[image]

I have a shower handle with the style included in the image.  I don't suppose I get the terminology correct, so I can't find my problem mentioned elsewhere.  But the portion circled in red keeps on falling off because the screw attaching at the end circled in blue won't stay screwed in.  Upon inspection of the screw, it doesn't look stripped, so I don't know that simply replacing the screw would do it.  What can I look at so I have a screw which stays in and the red portion doesn't fall off so I can rotate the handle on and off?

Comment: Could be the hole the screw threads into is stripped, especially if a softer(plastic) material.

Comment: Some Loctite might help if the threads aren’t totally gone.

Comment: Why not provide a picture of your _actual_ faucet instead of picking a "similar" image from the internet? Someone might just spot something on _your_ handle that you don't see as an issue and be able to guide you to a fix you weren't expecting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start out by removing the loose piece, clean the surface area of both parts that fit together. Reassemble and add a few drops of thread lock to the screw threads and screw it into place. Let it dry completely before putting any stress on it.